# Can a SharePoint 2010 Search field exist outside of SharePoint but search a SharePoint site list?

Tags: search

Wondering if it is possible to embed a SP search form in a normal html page but when information is entered then it go to the SP2010 site and search a list for results.

Comment: You mean open SharePoint search results page on clicking Search Button and display the results?

Comment: Correct basically I am trying to see if someone had a static non SharePoint site can they have a search box linked to my SharePoint site. They would start on site A non SP and after entering search words after hitting enter end up on Site B getting results from an SP site.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your html page and add a textbox and a search button. Then use following JavaScript

```
jQuery("#buttonId").click(function(){
    var val = jQuery("#searchBoxId").val();
    if(val == ''){
        alert('Please enter search term');
    }
    else{
        var url = "http://sharepoint/searchcenter/results.aspx?k=" + val;
        window.location.href = url;
    }
});
```

Results page should have a scope set to your list in the question. For creating scopes follow http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792872.aspx

After that you should add a new rule to the scope. The rule type should be set to `WebAddress` and enter the list URL.

Comment: I will try this try looks good.